# How to download specific files from some url path with wget

Tags: wildcards, wget

If I don't want to have to download the files found in a specific url path manually, what options do I have? Using wildcards fail:

```
$ wget 'http://www.shinken-monitoring.org/pub/debian/*deb'
Warning: wildcards not supported in HTTP.
....
```

This of course assumes that I don't know the filenames in advance.

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -A ".deb" http://www.shinken-monitoring.org/pub/debian/
```

`-r` recursively
`-l1` to a maximum depth of 1
`--no-parent` ignore links to a higher directory
`-A "*.deb"` your pattern

Comment: Although it's true in this case - this does assume that the web server returns a page at the URL that lists all the files.  If it returns an index page without any of the mentioned files, wget can magically get them.

Comment: I think that an option -nd also will be useful here. It allows to download matched files to the current directory without creating a hierarchy of directories.