# Wget list of files with predictable URL patterns programmatically?

Tags: wget

There are similar questions like this one, but nothing exactly the same. Using the new [Apple TV screensaver JSON resource](http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/000/Features/atv/AutumnResources/videos/entries.json) as an example, with predictable URLs, (only the numbers after the `b` and the `-` change, it seems like it should be fairly trivial to create a pattern that wget can use inside of a function. The latter number only goes up to `4` also.

`http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/000/Features/atv/AutumnResources/videos/b6-4.mov`

However, trying [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/540385/download-urls-listed-in-a-file-using-curl), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179008/wget-download-pics-with-particular-url-string) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18908/55531) fail, even with the `-nd` flag.

I feel like this is something simple and obvious I'm missing.

Comment: If you can somehow get a list of valid URLs, then you just need to run wget in a loop, or pass it `-i`. If not, it's very difficult; you'd need to brute-force it.

Comment: I mentioned the valid URLs. I also included the link.

Comment: Maybe: `wget http://..../b{1..10}-{1..4}.mov`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was a `wget` question, but if you're open to using `curl` here's how to do it:

Download and keep original filename

```
curl -O -L -f http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/000/Features/atv/AutumnResources/videos/b[1-10]-[1-4].mov
```

Download and use custom filename

```
curl -o screensaver-b#1-#2.mov -L -f http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/000/Features/atv/AutumnResources/videos/b[1-10]-[1-4].mov
```

If you wanted to multi thread it, you would just break up the first regex into.. something like:

```
curl -O -L -f http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/000/Features/atv/AutumnResources/videos/b[1-5]-[1-4].mov -O -L -f http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/000/Features/atv/AutumnResources/videos/b[6-10]-[1-4].mov`
```

`-0` download as same filename as what’s being served

`-o` customize downloaded file name

`-L` follow location headers

`-f` fail silently so you don’t download 404s